# Mjpg paparazzo.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip-camera, mjpeg

I'm trying to create a way to view my security cameras without browser support for mjpg streaming.
The paparazzo.js seems like a good solution to test out:
https://github.com/rodowi/Paparazzo.js/

There is a demo script and I've uploded it to my page homepage:
http://intra.tobiasfransman.net/talo/demo/demo.html

But it not displaying the test camera image.
Am I doing something wrong, shouldn't the demo work with default out of box parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Paparazzo.js runs on node.js.

So you need to install node.js, npm (node package manager) and download paparazzo.

After that:

1. `cd` into the directory where you downloaded paparazzo
2. run `npm install`

This will install all dependencies which paparazzo needs in order to function.

Finally `cd {Paparazzo_Install_Location}/demo` and run: 
`node bootstrap.js` -> Paparazzo should now be running.

Keep in mind that you have to edit the `server.coffee` file in `{Paparazzo_Install_Location}/demo` and the `demo.html` according to your needs (host, port, path etc.). From where to get the stream and on which port to respond.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't sound very confident